# How to convert IntoIterator<Item=AsRef<str>> to Iterator<Item=&str> in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm running Rust nightly (`rustc 1.50.0-nightly (f0f68778f 2020-12-09)`).

I learned about a way to accept (as a function parameter) arbitrary objects that can be converted to an iterator. I also learned about a way to do that to allow accepting both `String` and `&str` (and maybe other types that can be converted to `&str`) using `AsRef<str>`.

So far so good, I have a following test code that demonstrates that:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let v1: Vec<String> = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];
    let v2: Vec<&str> = vec!["a", "b"];
    let args: env::Args = env::args();

    fun1(&v1);
    fun1(&v2);

    fun1(v1);
    fun1(v2);
    fun1(args);
}

fn fun1<I, T>(args: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: AsRef<str>,
{
    println!("=================");
    for item in args {
        println!("{}", item.as_ref());
    }
}
```

It compiles nicely and runs fine. Now, my desire is to convert `args` from `IntoIterator<Item=AsRef<str>>` into `Iterator<Item=&str>` so I don't have to deal with those `as_ref()` calls throughout the function. In this example it's a simple loop that calls `as_ref()` in one place but my code that I'm not sharing here is more convoluted – I want to avoid calling `as_ref()` every time I get a next element out of that iterator.

Unfortunately my naive attempt to do so doesn't work:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let v1: Vec<String> = vec!["a".to_string(), "b".to_string()];
    let v2: Vec<&str> = vec!["a", "b"];
    let args: env::Args = env::args();

    fun2(&v1);
    fun2(&v2);

    fun2(v1);
    fun2(v2);
    fun2(args);
}

fn fun2<I, T>(args: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: AsRef<str>,
{
    println!("=================");
    let iter = args.into_iter();
    let mapped = iter.map(|item| item.as_ref());
    for item in mapped {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```

```
% rustc test1.rs 
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `item`
  --> test1.rs:23:34
   |
23 |     let mapped = iter.map(|item| item.as_ref());
   |                                  ----^^^^^^^^^
   |                                  |
   |                                  returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                                  `item` is borrowed here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
```

and for the life of me I can't get around this (I played with various approaches and all I got was errors like this), I looked through some previous questions and no luck.

Is there even a way to achieve this in Rust?

Comment: You could shadow the `item` variable with `let item = item.as_ref();` at the start of your `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah, but see this part of my question:

"In this example it's a simple loop that calls as_ref() in one place but my code that I'm not sharing here is more convoluted – I want to avoid calling as_ref() every time I get a next element out of that iterator"

Comment: FWIW, you can also use `&item` instead of `item.as_ref()`.

Comment: `&item` will give me type `&T` instead of `&str` though so it won't do.

Comment: Apologies, I mistakenly assumed that Deref coercion would take into account `Borrow`/`AsRef` implementations.

Comment: I don't think that's possible because `into_iter` takes ownership. So when you call `next` (or when to for loop does it for you), the item is moved from the original container. If you then want to take a reference to it, the item must still be stored somewhere, but where?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without collecting all of the data in the iterator into a `Vec` or similar. This is because an `Iterator<Item = &str>` requires that the string data behind the slices is not owned by the iterator, but an `Iterator<Item = String>` *does* own the string data by virtue of using an owned type.

This also explains why collecting into a vector works. In that case, the string data would be owned by the vector, and not the iterator, which satisfies the requirement that the `Iterator<Item = &str>` does not own the string data.

```
fn fun2<I, T>(args: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: AsRef<str>,
{
    println!("=================");
    
    let vec: Vec<T> = args.into_iter().collect();
    
    let mapped = vec.iter().map(|item| item.as_ref());
    for item in mapped {
        println!("{}", item);
    }
}
```

Note that it is not *always* the case that an `T: AsRef<str>` type owns the string data. For example, if `T = &str`, then it doesn't. Unfortunately generic code *must* handle all cases allowed by the generic parameters, so if the code does not handle the `T = String` case, it wont compile.

Note that in the case of `T = &str`, then the vector in the above example does not own the string data. Still, this is ok, because in that case, the string data is owned by some other collection entirely outside of `fun2`, and that *also* satisfies the requirement that `Iterator<Item = &str>` must not own the string data.